# binding ng-include src using $scope property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angularjs app I want to dynamically load partial view, so I have in my view

```
<ng-include src="'{{ pathView }}'"></ng-include>
```

this view is ofcourse attached to certain controller and in my controller I have

```
 $scope.pathView= "/templates/listView.html";
```

this not work since when investigating html view I'm getting

```
<!-- ngInclude: undefined -->
```

When I hardcode template view path

```
<ng-include src="'/templates/listView.html'"></ng-include>
```

it works.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`src` in `ng-include` needs a angular expression [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) , so you can bind that to the model value as below

```
<ng-include src="pathView"></ng-include>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `{{` and `}}`

Correct way `<ng-include src="pathView"></ng-include>`